# using config.groovy in gwt for user preference

Tags: grails, gwt

I have a gwt and grails legacy app that I'm upgrading and modifying.. Its a reservation calendar basically with different "views".. the problem I'm having is I want the user to be able to choose a default view for themselves upon logging in..I've done this with a grails only application before but gwt is much different..how can I pass something from config.groovy to the gwt part that select which view to show..and this view isn't a view like a grails view..think of it like restaurants..and a user may only want to see the reservations for a particular restaurant instead of the default of all restaurants

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe not a direct answer to your question but you can just make a ordinary GWT remote service `UserPreferencesService` which will store user preferences

```
public interface UserPreferencesService extends RemoteService {
    List<Restaurant> getRestaurants(Account user);
    void setRestaurants(Account user, List<Restaurant> restaurants);
}
```

In your entry point you can then make a decision on what kind of view you'll show to user

```
public final class Application implements EntryPoint {
    private AuthServiceAsync authService = 
        GWT.create(AuthService.class);
    private UserPreferencesAsync preferencesService =
        GWT.create(UserPreferencesService.class);

    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        // handle login
        authService.getAccount(new Callback<Account>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(final Account account) {
                // check if user have a preferred restourants
                preferencesService.getRestaurants(account, 
                    new Callback<Account>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(final List<Restaurant> restaurants) {
                            // user did not select any restaurants yet. 
                            // Show a selection widget
                            if (restaurants.isEmpty) {
                                RestaurantSelectorWidget widget =
                                    new RestaurantSelectorWidget();

                                // your custom handler here
                                widget.addHandler(new Handler() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSelected(/*...*/) {
                                        // save user preferences
                                        // and switch to normal view
                                    }
                                })
                                RootPanel.get("container")
                                         .add(widget);
                            } else {
                                // show normal view
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Also you may take look to [this](https://grails.org/plugin/gwt) plugin which is adds GWT support to grails.